# Cassandra - Every command issued in CQLSH throws errors

Tags: cassandra, cql, cqlsh

Cassandra gives me serious headache. Yesterday, everything was running fine and then I dropped a table, ran a CQLSSTableWriter which somehow threw errors about my [Lucene index](https://github.com/Stratio/cassandra-lucene-index) (for not being on classpath or the like) several times and now, every command I issue in the cqlsh is throwing errors.

```
CREATE KEYSPACE IF NOT EXISTS mydata WITH replication = {'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': '1'};
```

takes a while and then throws:

```
Warning: schema version mismatch detected, which might be caused by DOWN nodes; 
if this is not the case, check the schema versions of your nodes in system.local and system.peers. 
OperationTimedOut: errors={}, last_host=XXX.XXX.XXX.20
```

After that I will create a new table and it will also throw the same error.

```
cqlsh:mydata> create table test (id text PRIMARY KEY, id2 text);
Warning: schema version mismatch detected, which might be caused by DOWN nodes; if this is not the case, check the schema versions of your nodes in system.local and system.peers.
OperationTimedOut: errors={}, last_host=XXX.XXX.XXX.20
```

`last_host` always shows the ip of the host where I run the cqlsh on. I have tried the same commands with different nodes too.

The keyspace and table however is still being created! The error says something about mismatching schema versions, so I made sure and ran:

```
nodetool describecluster
```

And the output of it shows that all my nodes are on the same schema. No schema mismatches. I also issued `nodetool resetlocalschema` before, without any luck though.

When I go ahead and insert some data into the newly created table, following error arises. Note that the insert statement does not return an error.

```
cqlsh:mydata> insert into test(id, id2) values('test1', 'test2');
cqlsh:mydata> select * from mydata.test ;
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/cqlsh.py", line 1314, in perform_simple_statement
    result = future.result()
  File "/usr/share/cassandra/lib/cassandra-driver-internal-only-3.0.0-6af642d.zip/cassandra-driver-3.0.0-6af642d/cassandra/cluster.py", line 3122, in result
    raise self._final_exception
Unavailable: code=1000 [Unavailable exception] message="Cannot achieve consistency level ONE" info={'required_replicas': 1, 'alive_replicas': 0, 'consistency': 'ONE'}
```

Note that I have one datacenter and five nodes. I do not plan to use more than one datacenter in the future. [cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.0.8 | CQL spec 3.4.0 | Native protocol v4]

I have also restarted Cassandra multiple times. `nodetool status` shows that all nodes are up and running. Does anyone have a clue about what's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this by...

1. dropping all tables in the keyspace
2. running `alter keyspace mydata WITH replication = {'class': 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'dc1': '1'};` instead of `SimpleStrategy`
3. restarting the cassandra service on all nodes
4. recreating all tables
5. runnning `nodetool repair`

Now I am able to insert data and query data again. Still not quite sure what was the cause of all this to be honest though.

Comment: Typically, schema disagreements can be fixed by restarting the affected nodes (which you can see by running a `nodetool describecluster`.  Glad you got it fixed, though.

Comment: @Aaron This was exactly the part that caused headache for me. The output of `nodetool describecluster` has been like this for the entire time: `9ae01f7c-c138-31ee-a9d1-d11527c2471b: [xxx.xxx.xxx.24, xxx.xxx.xxx.28, xxx.xxx.xxx.30, xxx.xxx.xxx.32, xxx.xxx.xxx.20]

                UNREACHABLE: [127.0.0.1]`. As stated in the question above, I was expecting this to mean that there is no schema disagreement.

Comment: `UNREACHABLE: [127.0.0.1]` concerns me.  If that's not a valid node in your cluster, I'd do a `nodetool removenode` on it...and then delete it from system.peers on all other nodes.  Otherwise that 127.0.0.1 will be stuck on the old schema, and keep reporting disagreement.

Comment: @Aaron I've successfully removed the node `127.0.0.1` now. `nodetool describecluster` now shows a valid output, not including the `127.0.0.1` node. Thanks for your help.